# Same color text/background still ocassionally on Meta

Tags: bug, design, meta

I've seen a few examples of things where there is white text on white backgrounds on Meta, and just thought I'd show a few screenshots.

[image: Moderator info on a user]

[image: Favorite questions]

[image: Favorite question plus dropdown]

Under a user page, the Favorites tab.  Any newly-favorited (since the last time you viewed the Favorites tab) questions are like this.  Same happens for the other tabs on the user page:
[image: User page-> Favorites]

Links in spoiler tag blocks are a dark brown on the dark gray background of the spoiler block. As seen [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3115/).

The list of Responses on Meta display a light text on white background, but it seems they only display that way on *new* responses*:

[image: User Page-> Responses (new)]

[image: User Page-> Responses (new)(highlighted)]

The dates of events in timelines (`https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/$ID/timeline`) is in light gray over light gray.

[image: Timeline]

Comment: Added another image.  Looks like your second pic is only on favorite tags.

Comment: I added two more images

Comment: Browser / OS might be useful to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @bitmask: I've seen it with Firefox, Windows 7/ XP.

Comment: @bitmask My screenshots were from Chrome, Windows 7 Pro. I suspect this is a stylesheet issue, rather than a browser/OS bug, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Beofett: My Opera on Linux x86_64 has never shown such problems. Then again, Opera does have proper standards support (*SCNR*).

Comment: @bitmask Keep in mind that it appears most of the behavior you or I would see (i.e. non-moderator pages) are only on new, previously-unviewed entries. For example, my "responses" section of my meta profile showed 3 new entries; they are all white on white background, but the rest are on black background. [Take a look](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2565/bitmask?tab=responses) and see if this response shows there in the proper color scheme.

Comment: @Beofett: Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @bitmask I just tested checking your response in Opera (same computer I normally use Chrome on; I have all the major browser installed).  Your last response is light text on light background, as in the screenshot above.

Comment: @Beofett: Okay, that's strange; now it's broken here, too. Never seen that bug before.