# Asking a question about a film that is not fantastic, but its protagonist believes he lives in a tolkienesque fantasy world

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

The main character is a misfit living with his mother. There are no supernatural or preternatural elements in the story aside from the protagonist's psychosis (he believes that he is living in a tolkienesque fantasy world), but his psychosis is extremely important in defining his actions.

**Would this be on-topic as described?**

Comment: I'd say off topic - try [movies.se] instead, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of [Are works that may or may not just be dreams on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3450/20774). The consensus of opinion was that works are on topic if they have a significant fantasy content, **regardless of the source**

Comment: @Valorum that would be difficult to judge, I mean how much fantasy content is "significant".

Comment: Further to @Mithrandir's comment, if you do try [movies.se], please be aware that they have significantly more stringent criteria for ID questions than we do (due to a surfeit of bad ID questions) - see their guidance and lists [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info).

Comment: @AlienWerepandaolf - Significant (in my book) means "*taking up a sizeable chunk of the action or contributing significantly to the plot"*. Scrubs doesn't count, but Sucker Punch would, for example.

Comment: Not _[Mazes and Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazes_and_Monsters)_, is it?