# Is a TV film about a guy obsessed with fantasy stories on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I remember a particular TV film where the protagonist becomes obsessed with his inner world of high fantasy and this becomes an important cause of his actions, but there were no other elements of fantasy in the story.

(Edited subsequently)

I must add that the actions of the protagonist are influenced by his inner world of fantasy, not only because it is very important to him, but because the protagonist believes that this fantasy world is real.

So it's not just the case of an RPG player obsessed with his hobby, but a situation similar to Don Quixote's: he sees giants instead of mills.

Comment: A question about a film about a man watching television is not on topic. A question specifically about the internal "*fantasy play-within-a-play*" would be on-topic.

Comment: Dupe of [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

Comment: Possibly parallel question, are any of the versions of *The Secret Life of Walter Mitty* applicable?

Comment: Not knowing which film you're talking about, some questions about it could be on-topic for the same reason some questions about [the Big Bang Theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-big-bang-theory) are on-topic: a not-by-itself-on-topic work exploring an on-topic one.

Comment: Is it _[Mazes and Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazes_and_Monsters)_ you were thinking about?

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/asking-a-question-about-a-film-that-is-not-fantastic-but-its-protagonist-believ?rq=1 might also be relevant, which itself is marked as a dupe of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/are-works-that-may-or-may-not-just-be-dreams-on-topic

Comment: O, my god. I asked this same question 9 months ago and I had forgotten... :*-(

Answer (score 8):

### Valid if the film depicts the fantastic elements as reality

If, within the film's context, the fantastic bits are shown as reality within its context. So if you have a guy involved in a D&D analogue who visualizes the events of the game as actually happening, that would be valid, I think.

### Ambiguous if not

We allow for discussions of fantastic pieces of fiction (discussing a film with dungeons and dragons in it). We allow for metafictional discussions about the creators of fantastic fiction (why did Gary Gygax decide to call it "Dungeons and Dragons?"). Where it gets a little tricky would be if we had a film about someone who creates fantastic fiction (say, a film about Gary Gygax and his struggles with the industry) or even a film about someone who creates fictional fantastic fiction (the saga of someone creating *Mercenaries and Mangonels*).

Personally, I think that it would be valid only if we see the fantastic world depicted as a significant element, but not if it's just about boardroom meetings and the arguments he has with his wife over neglecting his children in favor of polyhedral dice.

Comment: "*I think this counselling for my addiction to RPG is going [rolls a 9] quite well"*

Comment: Re "a film with Gary Gygax" - If the question were along the lines of "The film says X happened while Gygax was developing *Dungeons and Dragons* - Is that true?" then I would call it very much on-topic as fandom information about *Dungeons and Dragons*, never mind what the film has to do with it.

Comment: Honestly, now I kind of want to make a movie about an ersatz Gary Gygax and his struggle to get *Mercenaries and Mangonels* into print...