# Is the "The Wizard of Oz" movie actually on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

At the end of *The Wizard of Oz* (the movie)

> Dorothy wakes up and it turns out that almost the whole movie was just a dream.

However, we have (according to [this query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bthe-wizard-of-oz%5D+movie+is%3Aq)) around 10 questions about the movie. **Why is this movie on-topic here?**

Comment: Dupe of [Are works that may or may not just be dreams on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/are-works-that-may-or-may-not-just-be-dreams-on-topic/3451#3451)

Comment: Dupe of [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e/344#344)

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Are Life of Pi questions on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/are-life-of-pi-questions-on-topic)